# Why does this code cause segmentation faults?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, gcc

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
"xor %rax, %rax \n\t"
"push %rax \n\t"
"push $0x68732f2f \n\t"
"push $0x6e69622f \n\t"
"mov %rsp, %rbp \n\t"
"push %rax \n\t"
"push %rbx \n\t"
"mov %rsp, %rcx \n\t"
"mov %rax, %rdx \n\t"
"mov $0xb, %al \n\t"
"int $0x80 \n\t"
);
}
```

this it my code.
When using gdb, it seems that an error occurs in `ret <0>` generated during compilation. Can you tell me how to solve it? The environment is Ubuntu 20.04.3 and GCC 3.9.0.

Comment: Do not use the 32 bit `int $0x80` in 64 bit code. It will not work in particular if you try to pass addresses that are outside of 32 bit range, and the stack normally is.

Comment: @Jester Thanks to you, I solved it.